# Disable 'Loading Messages' on eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, settings

Eclipse is constantly running 'Loading Messages' from what appear to be various plugin sites as well as a main eclipse site (all reference a messages.xml file).  Is there a way to disable this?  They are never able to actually load as I am behind a proxy, so it just sits there and churn.  I've yet to find a solution to this.

Edit:

Most of the time, I have my active provider set to manual.  This is required on my end in order to access source code.  So I actually have eclipse set up to not use a proxy.  Because of this, eclipse can not contact any outside sites (but I don't have a choice on this issue).  The active provider is only native when set I need to download a plugin for the first time (or manually update etc).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using Eclipse Helios (3.6).

Eclipse 3.6 should be able to detect a proxy.

Under Window -> Preferences, General -> Network Connections, you should see all of the proxy entries and the proxy bypass defined.

Make sure you have the Active Provider as Native.

Comment: I have my active provider set to native only when I need to download a plugin.  Other times it is set to manual otherwise source code is not accessible due to how things are set up.  So I poorly worded the question.  I'll change it to more actively reflect the situation.

Comment: @Joseph:  Set the Active Provider as Native, let Eclipse do its thing while you go get some coffee, and set the Active Provider back to Manual when you're ready to work.  I know, it's klutzy.

Comment: I'd rather just let the annoying messages thing churn while I work.  Thanks for looking at it though.  It seems to go away once in a while, then come back a while later.